# labels centered between ticks in a gauge

Tags: highcharts

I have made a windgauge with a beaufort scale (see http://meteo-alkmaar.dyndns.org/sl/af.html ).
Is there a way to center the labels between the ticks.(the green scale)
Thanks
Theo

Comment: This should be possible to achieve by using categorized axis, however doesn't work. So I have reported bug [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2460).

Comment: I made a second beaufort scale with the label between the ticks of the first scale.

Comment: I am happy with it now. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Only the behavior of the winddirection dial is acting strange when the wind turns from 5 deg to 355 deg or vv. It goes all around and that is not realistic. I already placed a question about this item but did not get the right answer.

Comment: If you want to dial goes the closest path to designed point, the answer is no - this is not directly supported. This should be possible by using some point updates.

Comment: That is a pitty. It only occurs when the wind comes from the north regions. Perhaps in a next update. Thank you anyway.